# Вставить символ после второй буквы в строке

Tags: php

возникла необходимость вставить `!` после второй буквы в строке.

пробовал такой вариант `wordwrap($string, 4, "!", true);` но проблема в том, что если текст русскоязычный, то появляются какие то знаки вместо букв типа таких `�`.

Comment: Настройте кодировку

Comment: тебе надо пользоваться этими функциями https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 1):

можно регулярки взять

```
 preg_replace("/^(..)/u", '$1!', $string)
```

- `^` начало строки
- `.` любой символ, соответственно 2 точки это два символа
- `(..)` оборачивая в скобки выделяем "группу захвата"
- `$1` в замене обращаемся к первой захваченной группе. в `$0` содержится все соответствие

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовавшись [строковыми функциями для многобайтных кодировок](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php) можно сделать так:

```
$str = 'привет';
$newStr = mb_substr($str, 0, 2) . '!' . mb_substr($str, 2);
echo $newStr . "\n";  // пр!ивет
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ:

```php
$str = 'hello';
$str[2] = 'L';
echo $str . "\n"; // heLlo
```

https://replit.com/@w3lifer/SqueakyOvalMigration#main.php

Comment: Ну а если вместо `hello` будет `привет`?

Comment: @u_mulder, а да, это я упустил ...

Answer (score 0):

Я не верно выразился, необходимо вставить после каждой второй буквы. не считая пробелы и знаки препинания... пока получилось только так.
`

```
$text = "Однажды, в студеную зимнюю пору,
Я из лесу вышел; был сильный мороз.";
    $you_char = "1";
    $text=preg_replace('/((?:.|\n){2})(?!$)/u','${1}'.$you_char,$text);
    echo $text;`
```

но он считает все символы.